# Installing Ubuntu on a laptop with Windows 10

Tags: system-installation

I have two drives (C, D) on my laptop and Windows 10 is installed on C.

Now, if I install Ubuntu 14.04 and choose the option "Replace Windows with Ubuntu", will it delete all current data from my D drive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it will. In fact, it will delete all the windows partitions C and D. First, you should create different partitions for ubuntu and create a backup for windows so that in case of any mistake, you will not use your data. Then, you should go for something else option. For step by step method, a good tutorial:

http://www.everydaylinuxuser.com/2015/11/how-to-install-ubuntu-linux-alongside.html

It will Dual boot windows and ubuntu. It means you can use both windows and ubuntu.

If you want to install only ubuntu,then go for the replace windows with ubuntu options. I think you are a newbie, so you should go for dual boot.

Answer (score 0):

every operating system take independent partition.when you will install any os on any partition then it must format first and then install on drive.easy way to install any linux version from windows,use wubi.exe installer instead of bootable os.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer is yes, it will probably delete partitions C and D if they are not separate disks.

The propblem is that Windows does not make difference between disks and partitions. You may have two physical disks or two partitions on one disk, but Windows will not show it.

When Ubuntu installer tells you that all data will be wiped from your disk, it means that the whole physical disk will be wiped.

Anyway you can install Ubuntu on your D partition if you choose manual method and tell the installer to wipe where to install Ubuntu.